# Evaluate indefinite integral. $\int\sqrt{225-t^2}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate indefinite integral: $$\int\sqrt{225-t^2}dt$$I have done integration before, but a similar problem to this one is stumping me I want to try to solve this and compare it to my actual problem. How start off?

Comment: Let $t=15\sin\theta$. You will end up integrating a constant times $\cos^2\theta$.

Answer (score 3):

Write the integral as $$\int b\cdot\sqrt{1-(ax)^2}dx$$ and change $t=ax$. You end up at:

$$\int \sqrt{1-t^2}dt$$ now put $t=\sin\theta$. You end up at:

$$\int \cos^2\theta d\theta$$

Comment: okay I see what you are doing

Comment: (225/2)arcsin(t/15)+(t/2)sqrt(225-t^2)+ C would this answer suffice?

Comment: yes that fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method called trigonometric substitution:

So, construct a triangle with legs, $t$, $\sqrt{225-t^2}$, and hypotenuse $15$.

Now,

Let $\sin \theta = \frac{t}{15}$, so $t = 15\sin \theta$

Then $dt = 15\cos\theta d\theta$

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=15\sin\theta$, then $dt=15\cos \theta d\theta$, $ $ so $$
$$ $\int\sqrt{225-t^2}dt$ = $15\int\cos^2 \theta $ $d\theta$ = $15/2$$(\theta +\sin 2\theta/2)$ $$
$$ Now resubstitute back for $\theta$, you get your answer. Hope you got it !!!